# Change size of slideshow in blogger

Tags: slideshow, blogger

I am using a picasa slideshow widget on my blogger, I would like to customize it so it's a little bigger and it lines up in the center of the right side.  I looked into the HTML code but can't find any code that allows me to change the size. Any suggestions?

its on this blog http://www.sequenceunlimited.com/

Comment: this link helped me,  now i need to just move it over to the left a little to line it up  http://newaspirations.blogspot.com/2011/08/how-to-change-slideshow-width-and.html

Comment: I think the alignment is proper!

Comment: no its more to the left. wait for side widgets to close and you'll see.

Comment: Can you provide any code at all?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to move the slideshow to the left paste the following code into your CSS section. The -20px pushes the slideshow 20px from the right,so change it accordingly.

```
#Slideshow1 {
margin-left: -20px!important;
}
```

Comment: I think your slideshow widget is perfectly aligned,but anyway try the above codes.

Comment: no its more to the left. wait for side widgets to close and you'll see.